# Subset dataframe and apply test

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataset with two column values I want to test with a Wilcoxon test.

I need to apply the test filtering the dates at different levels, applying the test on some predefined intervals.

Here's my code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(42)

df <- data.frame(matrix(rpois(n = 500, lambda = 12), ncol=2))
df$date <- sample(seq(as.Date('2017/01/01'), as.Date('2017/01/31'), by="day"), nrow(df), replace = TRUE)

# calculate endopoints 
endpoint_1 <- max(df$date) - weeks(1)

endpoint_2 <- max(df$date) - weeks(2)

# test endpoint 1

df %>%
  filter(date < endpoint_1 ) -> df1

wilcox.test(df1$X1, df1$X2)

# test endpoint 2

df %>%
  filter(date < endpoint_2 ) -> df2

wilcox.test(df2$X1, df2$X2)
```

I believe it's a very inefficient way to do it.

How can filter the dataset at there two lags and access the test results in a cleaner way?

Comment: what is `weeks`? Are you using any packages?

Comment: I'm sorry it's lubridate. Updated.

Comment: It seems quite efficient to me, did you mean inelegant ? or speed is really an issue ? I see that max(df$date) is computed twice, and that you're filtering unsorted data several times so if you do it for a big amount of endpoints you may sort your df once and use a more efficient filtering I suppose.

Comment: I don't know if there's a nice way to deal with lists with pipe, so it's not super elegant either, but this will work on one line: `lapply(max(df$date) - c(weeks(1),weeks(2)),function(x){filter(df,date < x) %>% with(wilcox.test(X1, X2))})`